# Why does the input name has to be different when sharing components?

Tags: angular

I had a difficult trying to figure out why my code could NOT get the number of items in featured items until I changed the variable from "input" to "search" in featured items. Below is my featured-item.component.html:

```
<rb-featured-item [search]="searchFeaturedItem" [isWhole]="isWhole" 
 [minMax]="isFeaturedMin">
</rb-featured-item>
<rb-product-list [searchType]="searchType" [subType]="subType" 
 [input]="searchStr" >
</rb-product-list>
```

Below is my featured-item.component.ts:

```
searchStr: string;
searchType: string;
subType: string;

searchFeaturedItem: string = 'cell phones'; // show all featured items in cell phones..   
isFeaturedMin: boolean = true;
isWhole: boolean = true;

ngOnInit() {
  this.searchStr = 'cell phones';     // product-list searches for all cell phones in su-category..
  this.searchType = 'sub-category';
  this.subType = 'none';
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Below is my featured-items.component (shared component). This is where my code can NOT get the number of items until I changed from 'search' to 'input'. Is it because product list has

```
<rb-product-list [input]> //and 
<rb-featured-item [input]>
```

Why I am getting an error?

```
//selector: 'rb-featured-item' -- see top
export class FeaturedItemComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input ('search') searchStr: string;   // ** errors if 'input' instead of 'search'***
  @Input('width') mainWidth: number;
  @Input ('leftMargin') mainLeftMargin: string;
  @Input('isWhole') isWhole: boolean; 
  @Input('minMax') isMin: boolean;  
  featuredItems: FeaturedItem[] = [];
  isFeatured: boolean;
```

[image]

Comment: I've also run into odd behavior for undocumented input names that cause issues. I can't remember if it was a problem with using existing HTML attribute names or if it was a problem with how annotations work in Typescript. Like you can't use a reserved word as an input name or something like that. Would be nice if Angular had a nice list of these to avoid in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

Input is a valid @input binding name. It can be used without errors. If you are having errors, it is unrelated to the fact that you used input as the name. To test this, I would try a different name than input, such as "someName" and see if you still run into issues. If you aren't, then it means that you have already binded "INPUT" to that component in some other way. On a side note, I would avoid naming your class variables differently than the template variables, as things will get really confusing. For example,

do this:

```
@Input ('search') search: string;
```

not this:

```
@Input ('search') myValue: string;
```

Nothing will break, it's just more consistent.

You should also avoid trivially inferred variables. For example, you have:

```
isFeaturedMin: boolean = true;
```

You are stating the type as boolean, but you are already instantiating it as a boolean, so there is no need to declare that it is a boolean. In some other languages (I think C+), this would be valid, but in Typescript, it should be one of these two:

```
isFeaturedMin = true; // Typescript knows it's a 
// boolean and you can never assign any other value that is not a boolean.
```

or

```
isFeaturedMin: boolean;

// later in your code:
isFeaturedMin = true;
```